# Bounding IntoIterator::Item

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

I have the following simple `struct`:

```
struct Stuff<T> { items: Vec<T> }
```

And, I want to set it up so that the `items` allow me to iterate them.  In particular, I'm expecting `&T` to implement `IntoIterator`.  Here's an example method which I managed to figure out that does compile:

```
impl<T> Stuff<T>
where
    for<'a> &'a T : IntoIterator {
    
    pub fn print(&self) {
      for item in &self.items {
        for j in item { print!("(?)"); }
      }
    }
}
```

I don't fully understand what's going on with `for<'a>`, or what difference it makes from writing `impl<'a,T>`, etc.  Anyway, I now want to require that `IntoIterator::Item` implements `fmt::Debug` so I could print them instead of `(?)`.  But, I seem to have hit a wall.   I tried this:

```
impl<T> Stuff<T>
where
    for<'a> &'a T : IntoIterator,
    for<'a> &'a T::Item : fmt::Debug
```

But, it says `associated type Item not found`.  I consider trying to have a second parameter `I` which was bounded by `&'a T`, that would then allow me to write `I : IntoIterator` and `I::Item : fmt::Debug`.  But no dice.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

For this you have to use the fully qualified syntax, `T::Item` is not enough:

```
impl<T> Stuff<T>
where
    for<'a> &'a T : IntoIterator,
    for<'a> <&'a T as IntoIterator>::Item: Debug
```

Or you can add another generic argument and bind it in place, I find this easier to read:

```
impl<T, I> Stuff<T>
where
    for<'a> &'a T : IntoIterator<Item=I>,
    I: Debug,
```

About the difference between `for<'a> ...`  and `impl<'a,T>`, I think they are mostly equivalent in practical usage. If the restriction were in the definition of `Stuff<'a, T>` the lifetime would limit what you can declare, but in an `impl <'a, T>`? Not so much.